# JNI: How to get jbyteArray size

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, size, java-native-interface

### Background

I'm working with byte arrays in ***JNI***. And I can't get ***length*** of ***jbyteArray***. I'm writing code in ***eclipse*** in ***Windows 7***.

***Java code:***

```
private native int Enroll( byte[] pSeed );
```

***JNI code:***

In JNI I have a struct that have two members `unsigned long length` and `unsigned char     data[1]`

```
typedef struct blobData_s {
    unsigned long     length;
    unsigned char     data[1];
} blobData_t;
```

Now as my JNI function get as argument `jbyteArray jpSeed` i want to get the length of `jpSeed` and set it as length member of struct.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_Test_Enroll( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray jpSeed ){
     blobData_t* bd = malloc( sizeof(blobData_t) );
     bd->length = **Question 1**
     bd->data[1] = jbyteArray;
}
```

---

***Question 1:  How I can get the length of `jpSeed` in JNI ?***

***Question 2:  Will this code works correct `bd.data[1] = jbyteArray;` ?***

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. You can use `GetArrayLength(JNIEnv* env, jbyteArray array)` ***Read*** [***here***](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/array.html).
2. Not sure what you want to do, I assume you want the content of `jpSeed` in `bd.data[1]`.
   Anyways, accessing the contents of a byte array, should be done with `GetByteArrayElements(...).`

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

***Answer on Question 1.*** As `jpSeed` is `jbyteArray` it mean that you can get it's length by calling `GetByteArrayElements( ... )` functions that declared in JNI ( you can read documentation [***here***](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html) ) here the right code will be:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_Test_Enroll( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray jpSeed ){
     blobData_t* bd = malloc( sizeof(blobData_t) );
     bd->length = (*env)->GetArrayLength( env, jpSeed );
     .......
}
```

***Answer on Question 2.*** This `bd->data[1] = jbyteArray;` code is not correct as it will not be compiled the right solution for this part is:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_Test_Enroll( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jbyteArray jpSeed ){
     blobData_t* bd = malloc( sizeof(blobData_t) );
     .......
     jbyte* bytes = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements( env, jpSeed, 0 );
     bd->data[1] = bytes[1];
}
```

And don't forgot to release.